# How do you make the bezier curve radius larger?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to increase the radius for a bezier curve. What I have tried: 
*Edit Mode-> Radius*, this increases and decreases the lines (I think animation lines) but the radius remains the same.

Scale: this increases and decreases the object without changing the radius.
I cant find a way to do this.

In my viewport I have BezierCurve. Not a bevel. How can I increase the radius of this?

Comment: The *bevel size* is a property of the bezier curve.

Answer (score 1):

To turn a curve object into a "pipe" you can either increase the bevel size or add a bevel object. While in edit mode you can change the radius of each point in the curve to alter the size of the bevel at that part of the curve.

If you assign a taper object to the curve, this object controls the size of the bevel along the length of the curve and overrides any radius adjustment that may be set.

If changing the radius of a curve point does not change the size of the bevel then you would have a taper object assigned. you can either remove the taper object or edit it to get the radius along the curve that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a "pipe" shaped curve, all you have to do is enter edit mode, select the vertices you want to scale, and press Alt + S.  If you want to scale the whole curve, you can also do this by increasing the "Depth" amount in the curve panel in the properties panel.